# Scala: Replace keys in a map with an object?

Tags: scala

I've been doing some work with slightly complex maps, and the last problem I need to solve is replacing a `Map()` whose key is a `Option[Long]` and replace it with a key that is a `Option[User]`.

The Map looks like:

`(Map[ Option[Long], List[Tuple3[Job,Option[Client],Option[Project]]] ]()`

I have a List of `Option[User]`. I was thinking a foldLeft could do the trick, but the syntax is tricky for my amateurishness. I tried the following with no success:

```
theMap.foldLeft(users){
      (u,j) => 
        if(j._1!=None) {
          Map(u, j._2)
        } else {
          Map(User.placeholder, j._2)
        }
    }.flatten
```

The compiler error below suggests that I'm probably not getting the variables in the right places.

```
type mismatch; found : List[Option[models.User]] required: (?, ?)
```

How can this be properly accomplished?

**Edit:** Realized I need to also match the first `Long` key to the `user.id`. Going to update it if I figure it out.

Getting closer and just switching to mapping. But this is getting a little troublesome:

```
allJobs.map{
     case ((i,l)) =>
       val user = users.map{ user =>
         if(user.map(_.id)==i) user
       }
       Tuple2(user.head, l)
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then this should do it.

```
val userMap = users map {u => (u, theMap(u map {_.id})} toMap
```

I'm not sure how useful `Option` keys are here, since there can only be one `None` key but if you need to account for that key and it might not be in the `users` list then you can add it separately.

```
val newMap = if(theMap contains None) userMap + (User.placeholder, theMap(None)) 
             else userMap
```

Comment: Whew that's clean. I see where I got stuck on the syntax and I was unaware of that nifty `toMap`. The `None` is indeed important since I will need to output jobs that have no associated user. Thank you very much for the help!